# Set of primetwins below 30

Tags: logic, prime-numbers

The Subset $C$ of the primes between 1 and 30, which have at least one primetwin (eg. 11,13).

Would this be correct?

$C=\{x\in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\} :(\nexists a\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,x\}(a\mid x))\wedge (((\nexists b\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,(x+2)\}(b\mid (x+2))\vee ((\nexists c\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,(x-2)\}(c\mid (x-2)))\wedge (x<30)\}$

apart from the simple listing of the twins.

Comment: Every natural number is divisible by 1 and itself so you delimited the nullset.

Comment: oh, ok i will edit the 1 out

Comment: 29 is in your set but not 31 or 27.

Comment: @shai horowitz 27 is not prime and 31 is >30

Comment: I know i'm just mentioning because its ambiguous to whether you wanted it in your set.

Comment: ah, ok i understand, you mean maybe "all primes which have a primetwin which is also in the set" vs "all primes with a twin", did there come the ambiguity?

Comment: what prevents a from being equal to x in the negation? otherwise its the same problem with 1 and the null set.

Comment: Looks good to me, make sure you have the right number of parenthesis.

Comment: @shaihorowitz thanks for helping on the fly :)